# Can I mix RAID-0 and RAID-1, i.e., striping and mirroring?

Tags: hard-drive, dell, mirroring, raid

With my Dell Precision Workstation T7400 came a SAS controller that supports both striping and mirroring. Total nr of physical connections is 4. What I'd like to do is plugin four 2TB disks, select two of them for striping and the other two for the mirror of the first two.

I know, RAID-5 would be more suitable here, but that's not supported as far as I can tell. Is this a common scenario and should this be possible with my hardware and/or with a new controller card?

Comment: Why is it that you think RAID5 would be more suitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be comonly known as RAID 1+0 or RAID 10.

Check whether your controller supports it ;) Being a SAS controller... it should.

Comment: Otherwise known as "Nested RAID."  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels

Comment: Ah, that's what that RAID-10 is all about. Thanks!

Comment: PS: as it turns out, Dell's SAS controller does *not* support RAID 10... :(